# Mac mojave - sudo uid reset

Tags: terminal, homebrew, zsh, sudo, macos-mojave

long story short,

1.my PATH got messed up so the zsh throws an "command not found" error in the terminal

2. tried to uninstall and reinstall the homebrew to see if that does anything - it did not.
3. now sudo throws me an error

```
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

the reason why(well my guess) sudo throws this error that is that while
I manually delete the files as the homebrew recommended, I must have deleted or done something in 
/usr/local so now sudo uid is not 0 anymore.

I have tried

```
mount -uw /
chown 0 /private/etc/sudoers
exit
```

and these instructions

A. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157772/sudo-etc-sudoers-is-owned-by-uid-501-should-be-0?fbclid=IwAR0HPT64TzzkuKs1ymsqb2l8HThXqRpGifX_QAdzrK5z5XgecavTzWiQVh0

B. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/not-able-to-use-sudo-commands-in-terminal.2101126/?fbclid=IwAR3BL-Sajkrsp02i5MCAKM7DZ0C83xUFOg9pzRhpG1hLrzpk9FbnDbbjoaM

but none of them worked.

What is the last thing I can do?
If I delete the drive and re-install it(disk utility), will it also change the sudo problem?
That is, of course, the last thing I would like to do. but I am considering it now.
Any thoughts?

HELP!

Answer (score 2):

After digging everywhere, I found the answer here,
[My sudo command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197232/my-sudo-command-not-working)

One of the main issues I had was that the sudo uid set to 501 instead of 0.

@GordonDavisson had a solution using "Script Editor" and run the code

```
do shell script "chown root:wheel /etc/sudoers; chmod 440 /etc/sudoers; chmod -N /etc/sudoers" with administrator privileges
```

as he mentioned.

This successfully changed my root. I checked it by running

```
ls -l /etc/sudoers
```

in the terminal.

After this, I could re-install the homebrew. 
Though I encounter unusual steps, where homebrew was running, 
it asked me several times to enter the password for different stages 
which did not happen before.

But after re-installing the Homebrew, I changed my $PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

and now I can live again!